# How to change the title of ios app in App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

As I understand it, in order to change the displayed title of my iOS app in the App Store, I need to resubmit or do an update of my app. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do an update to the App Store. Can somebody help?

Comment: Actually in iTunes Connect there are some tutorials which show how to upload an app and how to name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to iTunes Connect > Manage Your Applications > [Application Name] > Add Version (bottom right).